# How can I make VS parse .cshtml files using Razor in a .NET Framework Console App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

**What I'm doing:** Developing a `.NET Framework` console app that will self host an ASP.NET website (using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`).

**What I have:**
The console app works, it hosts the website at the given `domain:port`. I've configured it to use MVC, which also works, i.e. it finds the Controller when I go to http://localhost:1234/Home/Index.

**The Problem** Now, I want to use Razor. When I add `.cshtml` files, I get the following errors in the `Error List` window:
(These are not the build errors, but the errors that appear when opening a .cshtml file. If I close the file, the errors disappear. Plus, the project builds successfully even with these errors)

> '_Page_Views_Home__ViewStart___Copy_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override
>   The name 'Context' does not exist in the current context
>   The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context
>   The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exits in the namespace 'System.Web'
>   The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exits in the namespace 'System'
>   The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exits in the namespace 'System.Web'
>   The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exits in the namespace 'System.Web'
>   The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exits in the namespace 'System.Web'

*Funny how the last error appears thrice for the same file, same line.*

**Differences between *Console App (.NET Framework)* and *ASP.NET Web Application(.NET Framework)* I so far found:**

1. I created a new ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) and it had `.cshtml` too. But the above errors didn't appear.
2. I compared the two projects to see what's different. It had a `Web.config` file in the project root folder and `Views` folder. I copied then to the corresponding locations. **Didn't solve the problem**.
3. It also had Global.asax.exe and Global.asax.cs files. But they didn't seem to do anything to do with `.cshtml` files (or?).

How is my Console Application project different from the ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) **because of which I get the above errors for `.cshtml` files**?

**PS** Not generic difference. But specifically why doesn't VS parse the syntax in .cshtml files using Razor. Do I need to modify the .csproj file and configure something in there?

What can I do to correct this issue?

**Update**

I installed all the NuGet packages in the **.NET Framework Console Application** that were installed by default in **.NET Framework ASP.NET Web Application**. I still get the errors for .cshtml files. so I'm guessing it has nothing to do with the packages.

Now I have my attention on the .csproj files. So I'm comparing the project files for the 2 types of projects. Obviously they have differences, but I'm not able pin point at something.

I've added gists with .csproj files:

1. [.NET Framework ASP.NET Web Application](https://gist.github.com/xpleria/cc616f12ffabee36368edd9a203bc377)
2. [.NET Framework Console Application](https://gist.github.com/xpleria/f3467befa04322952a9fb3d2a4ee0f46)

Comment: You can create a Asp.net Core website on full .Net Framework which is a console app running Kestrel. Would that not suffice?

Comment: What's inside your .csproj?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I've added gists with .csproj files. Check question.

Answer (score 2):

An ASP.NET Core app *is* a console app. But, of course, not all console apps are ASP.NET Core apps. First and most importantly, you need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` NuGet package. Then, you have to actually bootstrap ASP.NET Core in your Program.cs. That's done generally via `CreateDefaultWebHostBuilder`, which you would then `Build` and `Run`. That only gives you the hosting infrastructure, though. Additionally, you then need to add in required services for the workflows you're using. For Razor view support, that's pretty much `services.AddMvc()`. You can either add that directly with web host builder via the fluent method `ConfigureServices` or via a `ConfigureServices` method in a `Startup` class (which you would then need to tell the web host builder to use). Finally, you need to actually activate the MVC machinery via `app.UseMvc`, which likewise would be called in the fluent method `Configure` or `Configure` on your `Startup` class.

While you can *technically* start from scratch with a plain old console app, the shear amount of bootstrapping required for most web application generally leads to creating an actual ASP.NET Core Web Application project being the best route. If you don't want to start a new project at this point, I'd still recommend creating an actual ASP.NET Core Web Application project, at least temporarily, as a guide for rejiggering your existing console application.

Comment: I've already done the bootstrapping you've mentioned. Also done AddMvc() n UseMvc(). The problem is VS gives the syntax errors mentioned above. I don't know how to tell VS to use Razor to parse the syntax in .cshtml files. I'm guessing I need to modify the .csproj file and configure something in that?

Answer (score 1):

An ASP.NET Core app is a .NET Core console app with some additional files. Web.config is not used by asp.net core apps, it is used only for IIS settings and is included in case you deploy to IIS.

ASP.NET Core apps DO NOT HAVE global.asax or global.asax.cs, that is only in older versions of ASP.NET

Older Console app is not .NET Core, it needs the full .NET desktop framework.